# spark scala pattern matching on a dataframe column

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I am coming from R background. I could able to implement the pattern search on a Dataframe col in R. But now struggling to do it in spark scala. Any help would be appreciated

problem statement is broken down into details just to describe it appropriately
DF :

```
           Case                      Freq
            135322                     265
     183201,135322                      36
     135322,135322                      18
     135322,121200                      11
     121200,135322                       8
     112107,112107                       7
     183201,135322,135322                4
     112107,135322,183201,121200,80000   2
```

I am looking for a pattern search UDF, which gives me back all the matches of the pattern and then corresponding Freq value from the second col.

example : for pattern `135322` , i would like to find out all the matches in first col Case.It should return corresponding Freq number from Freq col.
Like `265,36,18,11,8,4,2`

for pattern `112107,112107` it should return just `7` because there is one matching pattern.

This is how the end result should look

```
          Case                           Freq   results
            135322                       265    256+36+18+11+8+4+2
     183201,135322                        36    36+4+2
     135322,135322                        18    18+4
     135322,121200                        11    11+2
     121200,135322                         8    8+2
     112107,112107                         7    7
     183201,135322,135322                  4    4
     112107,135322,183201,121200,80000     2    2
```

what i tried so far:

```
val text= DF.select("case").collect().map(_.getString(0)).mkString("|")

 //search function for pattern search

 val valsum = udf((txt: String, pattern : String)=> { 
    txt.split("\\|").count(_.contains(pattern)) 
  } )

 //apply the UDF on the first col 
 val dfValSum = DF.withColumn("results", valsum( lit(text),DF("case")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works

```
import common.Spark.sparkSession
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import util.control.Breaks._

object playground extends App {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val pattern = "135322,121200" // Pattern you want to search for

  // udf declaration
  val coder: ((String, String) => Boolean) = (caseCol: String, pattern: String) =>
    {
      var result = true
      val splitPattern = pattern.split(",")
      val splitCaseCol = caseCol.split(",")
      var foundAtIndex = -1

      for (i <- 0 to splitPattern.length - 1) {
        breakable {
          for (j <- 0 to splitCaseCol.length - 1) {
            if (j > foundAtIndex) {
              println(splitCaseCol(j))
              if (splitCaseCol(j) == splitPattern(i)) {
                result = true
                foundAtIndex = j
                break
              } else result = false
            } else result = false
          }
        }
      }
      println(caseCol, result)
      (result)
    }

  // registering the udf  
  val udfFilter = udf(coder)

  //reading the input file
  val df = sparkSession.read.option("delimiter", "\t").option("header", "true").csv("output.txt")

  //calling the function and aggregating
  df.filter(udfFilter(col("Case"), lit(pattern))).agg(lit(pattern), sum("Freq")).toDF("pattern","sum").show

}
```

if input is

> 135322,121200

Output is

```
+-------------+----+
|      pattern| sum|
+-------------+----+
|135322,121200|13.0|
+-------------+----+
```

if input is

> 135322,135322

Output is

```
+-------------+----+
|      pattern| sum|
+-------------+----+
|135322,135322|22.0|
+-------------+----+
```

Comment: hi @Sanchit. I would like to get back the sum of Freq for every pattern matched. incase for `135322,121200` as pattern. There are 2 matches one is 4th row in case col and other is last row. hence sum of freq will be (11+2)=13. for pattern `183201,135322,135322` it will just one match. hence 4. does it make sense ?

Comment: Give me sometime.

Comment: Does it have to follow the sequence also? Like you mentioned 135322,121200 should return 4th and last row but the 5th row also has the same values

Comment: yes `135322,121200` and `121200,135322` are different patterns. it has to follow the sequence

Comment: Updated answer.
Have a look at the solution let me know if this works out.

Comment: thanks a ton for your solution. it seems to work partially. I tested for `121200,135322` pattern. but what it returns is `331` which must not be the case. it should return `10`

Comment: i also tested for pattern`183201,135322`, it should return `42` as sum, but returns `342`. This is because it is doing partial serach and hence, sum up rows like `135322`,`135322,135322`, `135322,121200`, `121200,135322`, and `183201,135322,135322`. This but actually has to sum just 2 rows `183201,135322` and last row `112107,135322,183201,121200,80000`

Comment: For pattern "183201,135322" the sum should be ? 40 or 42?
It should consider just row 2 and row last, isn't it?

Comment: for `183201,135322` the sum should be 42. it should consider row 2,7, and 8 .

Comment: But you mentioned "yes 135322,121200 and 121200,135322 are different patterns. it has to follow the sequence " in 8th row it doesn't follow the sequence?

Comment: my bad, got wrong. ` 135322,121200 and 121200,135322` are same patterns. I would edit the question. what needs to be edited in the current code to make it same pattern?